# Xamarin iOS tableview cell expand causes bottom section headers to slide up

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, tableview

[Gif of the Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7lJc.gif)

```
public override async void RowSelected(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{

   tableView.DeselectRow(indexPath,true);
   var myCell = _cellDataDict[_cellSectionList[indexPath.Section]][indexPath.Row];

   myCell.IsSelected = !myCell.IsSelected;

   if( _previousCell != null && _previousCell != myCell)
       _previousCell.IsSelected = false;


   tableView.BeginUpdates();
   tableView.EndUpdates();

   tableView.ScrollToRow(indexPath, UITableViewScrollPosition.Top, true);
}


public override nfloat GetHeightForRow(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
   var myCell = _cellDataDict[_cellSectionList[indexPath.Section]][indexPath.Row];

   if(myCell.IsSelected)
       return 293.0f;
   else
       return 68.0f;
}

public override nfloat GetHeightForHeader(UITableView tableView, nint section)
{
    return 44.0f;
}

public override nfloat EstimatedHeightForHeader(UITableView tableView, nint section)
{
    return 44.0f;
}

public override nfloat EstimatedHeight(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
   var myCell = _cellDataDict[_cellSectionList[indexPath.Section]][indexPath.Row];

   if(myCell.IsSelected)
       return 293.0f;
   else
       return 68.0f;
}
```

Basically I want to achieve expanding my table view cell then scrolling to the top of the tableview after it is expanded.  But the animation right now looks weird and I want to smooth it out.  It looks like the bottom section header slides up even though there is a copy already there.

Comment: is it not because of  `tableView.ScrollToRow(indexPath, UITableViewScrollPosition.Top, true);`

Comment: what is it then?